# Python alphabetical sort error in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I'm new to Python. I need to sort alphabetically the different genres I have in my object Genre_df which looks something like this with many more values below
[image: Screenshot of the object Genre_df]

However I'm not able to do it either with `sort_values` function.
I,m doing this:
    Genre_df = Genre_df.sort_values('Genre', ascending = False)

Its giving me this error:

> KeyError: 'Genre'.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). That also applies to text data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Genre is index in your DF.

Try:

```
Genre_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hey..Thanks that worked like a charm! However the count column still shows "Genre" as the column name.. Any idea why?

Comment: Hey.. silly of me.. renamed the column name.. But still a big thanks for sorting the index.!

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a problem with 'by' parameter, you can try this

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({
     'Genre': ['Drama', 'Comedy', 'Horror'],
     'Count': [689, 389, 115]
})
a.sort_values(by=['Genre'], ascending=False)
```